# AttributeError: module 'pywintypes' has no attribute '__import_pywin32_system_module__'

Tags: python, anaconda, command, attributeerror, pywin32

I am trying to use the conda command in Anaconda Prompt on Windows, but I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pywintypes' has no attribute '__import_pywin32_system_module__'
```

I have tried reinstalling PyWin32 using the following command:

```
pip uninstall pywin32 pywin32-ctypes
conda install pywin32
```

However, the error still persists. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Here is the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 142, in main
    from ..activate import main as activator_main
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .base.context import ROOT_ENV_NAME, context, locate_prefix_by_name
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .._vendor.appdirs import user_data_dir
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 337, in <module>
    import win32com.shell
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 4, in <module>
    pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module__("pythoncom", globals())
AttributeError: module 'pywintypes' has no attribute '__import_pywin32_system_module__'
```

**And I am trying to activate a Conda environment on Windows using the following command:**

```
D:\>conda activate testpyt
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 142, in main
    from ..activate import main as activator_main
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .base.context import ROOT_ENV_NAME, context, locate_prefix_by_name
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .._vendor.appdirs import user_data_dir
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 337, in <module>
    import win32com.shell
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "D:\Users\belongTH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 4, in <module>
    pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module__("pythoncom", globals())
AttributeError: module 'pywintypes' has no attribute '__import_pywin32_system_module__'
```

I have already tried reinstalling PyWin32 using the following command:

```
pip uninstall pywin32 pywin32-ctypes
conda install pywin32
```

But the error still persists. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I have the same error, did you solve the problem? if yes could you please help and put the solution in the comments!?
Thank you